# Convert byte array to string? ESP32 BLE firmware development

Tags: arrays, string, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, bluetooth-gatt

I am using an android app (mobile phone) and an ESP32, connected to each other via BLE. I am trying to send a string from the mobile phone to the ESP32. The android app sends a string in byte array form and the esp receives it. But I am having trouble retrieving the value on the ESP firmware.

Below is the code for the method that I tried. The whole point of this code is for the string that was sent from the android app to be stored in this variable: `INCOMING_STRING1`. I tried setting up the receiving variable as a character array (I think that's what this variable is for), and then used `strcpy` assuming that the contents of the incoming data (passed in through the character parameter) would be copied to `INCOMING_STRING1`, however, it doesn't work.

```java
    //Variables
    const uint8_t *character;
    char INCOMING_STRING1[64];

    //Elsewhere in code...
    //event comes from the ESP BLE module when a BLE event happens
    switch(event)
    {
        case ESP_GATTS_WRITE_EVT:
            writeHandle(param->write.handle);
            break;
        ...
    }

    //Elsewhere in code...
    static void writeHandle(uint16_t handle)
    {
        get_attr_ret = esp_ble_gatts_get_attr_value(handle, &length, &character);

        //There's different handles for different "channels"
        if(handle == 45)
        {
            //supposed to take string that was received
            strcpy(INCOMING_STRING1, character);
            //then print it to make sure
            printf("%s", INCOMING_STRING1);
        }
    }
```

I'm aware that this is probably a type miss match, since the incoming data is of type `uint8_t` and the variable to store the string is type `char`. I've always struggled with type casting and type manipulation in general, any help is appreciated!

Here's the error messages I get at this moment:

> error: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' differ in
>   signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
>       strcpy(INCOMING_STRING1, character);
>                                ^
>       note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'const uint8_t * {aka const unsigned char *}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close with your solution. It needs to minor fixes:

The first fix is to declare `character` differently:

```
const char *character;
```

`uint8_t` is an unsigned byte, `char` is usually a signed byte (it's unfortunately implementation defined).

The second problem is that the transmitted string is most likely not terminated with a 0 byte. So you cannot use `strcpy` and have to add the 0 byte yourself. So instead of `strcpy`:

```
memcpy(INCOMING_STRING1, character, length);
INCOMING_STRING1[length] = 0;
```

A further potential problem is the length of the string. By default, Android BLE will only transmit messages with a payload of up to 20 bytes. If the string is longer, is transmitted in several messages. So each time you call `esp_ble_gatts_get_attr_value`, you will only get a piece of the string.

So start your tests with small strings. If you run into a problem with longer strings, then change your Android code to increase the MTU of the BLE connection.

Comment: Hello @Codo thanks for your reply, unfortunately, get_attr_ret = esp_ble_gatts_get_attr_value(handle, &length, &character); requires that the character argument be of type uint8_t

Comment: Then you have to cast the argument, either in `memcpy(INCOMING_STRING1, (const char*)character, length);` or in `esp_ble_gatts_get_attr_value(handle, &length, &(const uint8_t**)character);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
//supposed to take string that was received
strcpy(INCOMING_STRING1.c_str(), character);
```

its a simple conversion method, you might wanna include the string library if you are not on arduino IDE.

```
#include <string>
```

Notice I didn't put the ".h" on the end of string, try it this way

Comment: Hello, @Nathan Almeida, unfortunately, the #include <string> can't be resolved :/